# When to use SSIS package instead of stored procedure? What we can achieve with SSIS that can also be achieved from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, ssis

When to use `SSIS` package instead of a stored procedure? What we can achieve with`SSIS`that can also be achieved by a `store procedure`?

Comment: Both have different purpose. Stored procedure is used to write business logic and data validations whereas SSIS is used to apply transformations on the raw data to make it meaningful and relevant for the purpose in hand.

Comment: SSIS can more easily access data outside your SQL Server (i.e. files. other SQL Servers) than a stored procedure. It can more visually describe the processes going on. But it's often slower that SSIS. If you really need to crunch local data it's often better to use a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be creating a large ETL then SSIS packages are the way to go. They allow for rapid development and re-use of code if you choose a nice design pattern. If you're just going to be using SSIS to execute a bunch of stored procedures or do something small, then you should probably use SQL. There's a bunch of factors you need to consider as well. SSIS has extensibility SQL does not, you can create script tasks in C# or VB and do things not possible in SQL. If speed is an issue, then most of your code should be written in SQL stored procedures and executed using Execute SQL Tasks in SSIS. Early development in SSIS usually starts off slow and then picks up once you have your initial design pattern set up nicely, whereas with writing an ETL in SQL you can pretty much jump into it straight away. The logging and audit trails in SSIS are easy to implement and help tremendously with debugging, trying to achieve the same level of logging detail is really tough when your ETL is written only in SQL. The GUI in SSIS also helps to visualize the dataflow in your ETL, it helps to identify bottle necks and just get a grasp over what you're building when it comes to very complicated projects.